# XSS not executing properly

Tags: xss, javascript, firefox

Instead of receiving Alert(XSS) I get `[object Object]`

The application is expecting a .csv file and the name of the file is being reflected. I put the original .csv file and then I remove it in order to put a file called `<IMG SRC="jav&#x09;ascript:alert('XSS');">`.

I think is the server side filter. Or maybe I can modify the source code. I don't know.

The application parses the .csv file in json so I dont know if it is a json error and not a javascript error

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you get an alert popup (that you weren't expecting) *at all*, you have XSS, which can do completely arbitrary stuff in the context of that site. Congrats (or condolences, if it's your site). The *point* of XSS is not to pop an alert, and it's definitely not to pop an alert with the exact string "XSS"! The point of XSS is to *execute arbitrary script* and `alert` is used in testing just because it's easy to see it happen, and you can use different strings in different injection points to see which one(s) fire(s).

Second thing: `[object Object]` is just the default value that all JS objects return when converted to a string (more specifically, it's the return value of the default `toString` function automatically added to all objects even if missing from their constructor/prototype). Since `alert` expects a string as its parameter, any object you pass to `alert` will be converted to a string (implicitly, because JS is an exceptionally loosely typed language) and - unless the object being passed has overridden the default `toString` - will thus be rendered as `[object Object]`. If you want it to display something else, pass a different value... but again, if you can call `alert` *at all* when the app doesn't normally do so, you have achieved XSS.

Third thing: this is probably not a server-side filter. It might be the result of some server-side logic that is, for example, replacing the uploaded file name (string) in the response with an object (that probably contains the file name as a member field). It could also be a client-side script doing the same thing, especially if the file isn't submitted directly to the server but goes through some client-side processing first. But it's probably not a *filter*, because if it was, it would be stripping out or sanitizing the entire injected script, rather than leaving the `alert` but changing the parameter. Remember, the ability to *call an arbitrary function* is the dangerous part, not the content of the pop-up!

---

To debug this, I recommend looking in two places:

1. In the webapp, after you've uploaded the malicious file name, look at the response from the server. Try searching for a part of your payload, such as the string "alert". See what parameter it ended up with!
2. Since your injection is a JS URI, rather than a script in the DOM, you should also look at the location bar of the window (or subwindow, such as an iframe) where the page attempts to load the file. What is the actual URI in that `window.location`?

For both of these, you *can* do them using the browser's built-in developer tools, but it might be easier (especially for the first) with an intercepting proxy.

---

One final note: you describe a multi-step attack vector, and one that probably requires a POST request. In order to make this viable for XSS, at least one of two things must be true:

1. You can make this request from another site (it doesn't have any CSRF protection, and either doesn't require any request properties that make it a non-simple CORS request or the preflight is approved for some reason).
2. You can upload the file yourself but then force *other logged-in users with different permissions from you* to view it, triggering the payload in their context. (Strictly speaking, the latter shouldn't be called "cross-site scripting" since it's generally happening entirely within one site and is instead "cross-user scripting", but everybody calls it XSS anyhow.)